# Retaining captures with the Perl substitution operator

Tags: regex, perl, capture

Can someone explain why the following code...

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string;

$string = "\t\t\tEntry";
print "String: >$string<\n";

$string =~ s/^(\t*)//gi;

print "\$1: >$1<\n";
print "String: >$string<\n";
print "\n";

$string = "\t\t\tEntry";

$string =~ s/^(\t*)([^\t]+)/$2/gi;

print "\$1: >$1<\n";
print "String: >$string<\n";
print "\n";

exit 0;
```

...produces the following output...

```
String: >           Entry<
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ~/sandbox.pl line 12.
$1: ><
String: >Entry<

$1: >           <
String: >Entry<
```

...or more directly: Why is the matched value in the first substitution not retained in $1?

Comment: funny, I'm not getting this warning with perl 5.12.2 on Linux. Could this be release-dependent?

Comment: perl, v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread, no warning, output as expected: $1: >(16? spaces not visible here)<

Comment: For the record, the version of Perl I'm using here is: This is perl, v5.8.9 built for darwin-2level

Comment: You should not rely on the values in capture buffers unless you know the match succeeded, and never in this context `s///g`.

Comment: why never in the context of the substitution operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried this on two implementations of Perl 5.12, and did not encounter the problem. 5.8 did.

Because you have the `g` options, perl tries to match the pattern until it fails. See the debug output below.

So it doesn't work in Perl 5.8, but *this* does:

```
my $c1;
$string =~ s/^(\t*)/$c1=$1;''/ge;
```

Thus each time it matches, it saves it to `$c1`.

This is what `use re 'debug'` tells me:

```
Compiling REx `^(\t*)'
size 9 Got 76 bytes for offset annotations.
first at 2
   1: BOL(2)
   2: OPEN1(4)
   4:   STAR(7)
   5:     EXACT <\t>(0)
   7: CLOSE1(9)
   9: END(0)
anchored(BOL) minlen 0
Offsets: [9]
        1[1] 2[1] 0[0] 5[1] 3[1] 0[0] 6[1] 0[0] 7[0]
Compiling REx `^(\t*)([^\t]+)'
size 25 Got 204 bytes for offset annotations.
first at 2
   1: BOL(2)
   2: OPEN1(4)
   4:   STAR(7)
   5:     EXACTF <\t>(0)
   7: CLOSE1(9)
   9: OPEN2(11)
  11:   PLUS(23)
  12:     ANYOF[\0-\10\12-\377{unicode_all}](0)
  23: CLOSE2(25)
  25: END(0)
anchored(BOL) minlen 1
Offsets: [25]
        1[1] 2[1] 0[0] 5[1] 3[1] 0[0] 6[1] 0[0] 7[1] 0[0] 13[1] 8[5] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 0[0] 14[1] 0[0] 15[0]
String: >                       Entry<
Matching REx `^(\t*)' against `                 Entry'
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=5
   0 <> <                       Entry>        |  1:  BOL
   0 <> <                       Entry>        |  2:  OPEN1
   0 <> <                       Entry>        |  4:  STAR
                           EXACT <\t> can match 3 times out of 2147483647...
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=5
   3 <                  > <Entry>        |  7:    CLOSE1
   3 <                  > <Entry>        |  9:    END
Match successful!
match pos=0
Use of uninitialized value in substitution iterator at - line 11.
Matching REx `^(\t*)' against `Entry'
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=5
   3 <                  > <Entry>        |  1:  BOL
                            failed...
Match failed
Freeing REx: `"^(\\t*)"'
Freeing REx: `"^(\\t*)([^\\t]+)"'
```

Because you are trying to match whitespace at the beginning of the line, you need neither the `g` nor the `i`. So it might be a case where you're trying to do something else.

Comment: @Axeman - shouldn't the ^ and the greediness of * capture all \t?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, I was wrong. See the revised post. I suspected it was the case, but wasn't sure until I ran it through `re debug`.

Comment: @Axeman - "only successful matches affect the capture variables" (Eff. Perl Prog. 104); neither the debug output nor the needless but harmless gi explain an empty $1 after an successful match. And: $1 isn't empty in/on/under at least two Perl installations.

Comment: The g and i modifiers were remnants of the previous version of the regex.  Removing them seems to have alleviated the issue, thank you.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner that's a totally valid point.  I do have the code working now, but I'd be curious as to why either of those flags would "break" the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think version 5.10 and beyond, it only affects capture buffers if there was a match.
The interesting thing in your example, is that with `$string =~ s/^(\t*)([^\t]+)/$2/gi;`
it didin't reset the capture buffers. That appears to be because of a preamble that estimates
if the match should be tried. In this case, `([^\t]+)` consumed the entire string in the first
match, so a `string too short` occured and the buffers were never reset.

I can't test it but `$string =~ s/^(\t*)([^\t])//gi` should give the same warning.
`if ( s///g ) {}` and testing of capture buffers in this case is not certain to contain
anything. This was the case in version 5.8. Even in later versions its really just a debug feature.

**Edit** @theracoon - on your comment: *"I'm reasonably certain that ([^\t]+) did not actually consume the entire string. The output definitely does not reflect that."*

This is a proof that your regex consumed the entire string on the first match, Pass 1.
There is nothing left to match on the second pass. That is the way the /g modifier works.
It tries to match the entire regex again, in the postion in the string where the last match left off.

```
use re 'debug';
$string = "\t\t\tEntry";
$string =~ s/^(\t*)([^\t]+)/$2/gi;
print "'$string'\n";
```

Pass 1 ..
Matching REx `"^(\t*)([^\t]+)"` against `"%t%t%tEntry"`
 8 <`%t%t%tEntry`> <>
Match successful!

Pass 2 ..
Matching REx `"^(\t*)([^\t]+)"` against `""`
 (Nope, nothing left to match)
String too short [regexec_flags]...
Match failed
'Entry'

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that ([^\t]+) did _not_ actually consume the entire string.  The output definitely does not reflect that.

Comment: @theracoon - For this I get a downvote? Lets test your theory: `$string =~ s/^(\t*)([^\t]+)//; print "'$string'\n";` Output `''` Nope, it consumes the entire string in the first match. The next match fails because the pool of remaining characters after the last match is empty.

Comment: yours: $string =~ s/^(\t*)([^\t]+)//; mine: $string =~ s/^(\t*)([^\t]+)/$2/gi;